# Gaussian Elimination with Partial Pivoting (Python) using M = np.column_stack ((a,b))

Tags: python

I am trying to write a Python function implementing Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting using this pseudocode:

```
M = [A b] 
for k=1:n-1 
    select i >= k to maximize |M(i,k)|
    M(k,k:n) <--> M(i,k:n)    (interchange two rows)
    for j=k+1:n
       q = M(j,k)/M(k,k)
       M(j,k:n+1) = M(j,k:n+1) - q*M(k,k:n+1)
    end
end
x(n) = M(n,n+1)/M(n,n)
for i = n-1:-1:1
    z=0
    x(i) = (M(i,n+1)-M(i, i+1:n)*x(i+1:n))/M(i,i)
end
```

I have tried coding it but it doesn't work and now I am stuck >< [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IioAH.png) I have to combine a and b into M but I couldn't at all. It get's complicated.

Comment: please add code as text not in an image

Comment: Please, add the code that you sent as an image, as a code in the question. If possible, explain the math behind this operation, so we can understand what you are trying to do. The majority of people here are good at software, but they will have no clue about your heavy math.